# Значение символа "$" в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Какое значение имеет символ доллара (`$`) в JavaScript? За что он отвечает и где его уместно использовать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Его можно использовать как короткое и нетривиальное имя для переменной. Это и делается во многих JavaScript-фреймворках. Например jQuery и Prototype.

Comment: а ещё ссылки на JQuery object принято именовать начиная с этого символа:

    var $div = $('#divId');

Comment: неплохо бы снабдить ответ примерами, а то как-то больно сухо

Answer (score 15):

Ничего особенного, просто этот символ [может использоваться](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/276994) в идентификаторах, в отличие от многих других языков. То есть `abc$def` -- законное имя переменной или функции, например.

Вы часом не спутали javascript с библиотекой jQuery? В ней `$` используется под имя глобальной переменной. Снова-таки, никакой магии, просто имя переменной.

Comment: Мне кажется товарищ путает с обозначением переменных в PHP.

Comment: @Lucky: или в perl, да.

Answer (score 7):

В JAVASCRIPT знак $ используется для интерполяции выражений:

```
let data = [11, 22, 33];
const str = `Number ${data[0]} from data`;
console.log(str); // Number 11 from data
```

(Только замените ' на `)

Answer (score 5):

это обычный символ.

```
var one$two = true;
alert(one$two);
```

Также знак доллара используется для получения доступа к главному объекту `jQuery`, если подключена эта библиотека.

Или `$(id)` в `prototype` означает

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

Comment: >Также знак доллара используется для получения доступа к главному объекту jQuery

не хочу показаться занудой, но всё таки "к функции jQuery"

Comment: @Spectre Ну я же не указал, как именно :-)

Comment: @Spectre Не хочу показаться занудой, но функции в JavaScript являются объектами https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Справочник_по_JavaScript_1.5/Глобальные_объекты/Function

Comment: >Не хочу показаться занудой

у вас это не получилось

Comment: @Spectre короче говоря у `Object` глобального объекта-класса стандартного объекта есть метод `toString()` который наследуется всеми объектами и вызывается интерпретатором при вызове `valueOf` первым и вы можете его переопределить: `$.prototype.toString = function(){return "В JS почти всё объекты";};`

Comment: Ваш пример выводит всего лишь исходный код функции. Я говорю о том, что фактически функции являются объектами. Введите в Вашей консоли $. и получите целую кучу методов объекта $

Comment: Короче читайте JavaScript The Definitive Guide желательно 6th edition я и сам не хотел читать: [Мой вопрос на hashcode](http://hashcode.ru/questions/148086/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-javascript "Книга про профессиональный JavaScript") но теперь признаю это единственная лучшая книга по JS

Comment: @Lucky я случайно написал `$.prototype.toString...` а надо `$.toString...` (после подключения библиотеки написать) теперь введите `$` в консоль :)

Comment: @Rules Мой предыдущий комментарий был обращен к @Spectre, а не к Вам.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
User: <input name="username" type="text"><br>
Email: <input name="email" type="text">
</form>

<script>
$('[name="username"]').val(app.user.username);
$('[name="email"]').val(app.user.email);
</script>
```

тут прикол в том что не надо использовать

```
document.getElementsByName('username')
document.getElementsByName('email')
```

а можно просто указать $ для получения доступа к главному объекту jQuery (как было сказано выше)

Answer (score -6):

```
<form>
User: <input name="username" type="text"><br>
Email: <input name="email" type="text">
</form>

<script>
$('[name="username"]').val(app.user.username);
$('[name="email"]').val(app.user.email);
</script>
```

Вот вам хороший пример использования $!
Думаю все стало ясно…

Comment: и чем же в вашем коде является `$`? пример чего вы привели? у меня, например в хроме, ваш код кидает исключение: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null_, либо как вариант: _Object doesn't support property or method 'val'_

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?